# Exception Handling by validating simple inputs

Tags: python, validation, exception

I am new to Python, after I managed to learn Java at an advanced level.
In Java input validation with exception handling was never a problem to me but somehow in python i get a little confused:

Here an example of a simple FizzBuzz programm which can only read numbers in between 0 and 99, if otherwise, an exception has to be thrown:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

def fizzbuzz(n):
    try:
        if(0<= n <= 99):
            for i in range(n):
                if i==0:
                    print("0")
                elif (i%3==0 and i%7==0) :
                    print("fizzbuzz")
                elif i%3==0:
                    print("fizz")
                elif i%7==0:
                    print("buzz")
                else:
                    print(i)    
    except Exception:
        print("/// ATTENTION:The number you entered was not in between 0 and 99///")   

try:
    enteredNumber = int(input("Please enter a number in between 0 and 99: "))
    fizzbuzz(enteredNumber)
except Exception:
    print("/// ATTENTION: Something went wrong here. Next time, try to enter a valid Integer ////")
```

If i run that and enter e.g. 123 the code just terminates and nothing happens.

Comment: You're not raising an exception in your code. If you learned Java to an "advanced level", you should know the difference between throwing an exception and catching one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to raise an exception from fizzbuzz() when your condition is not met. Try below:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

def fizzbuzz(n):
    try:
        if(0<= n <= 99):
            for i in range(n):
                if i==0:
                    print("0")
                elif (i%3==0 and i%7==0) :
                    print("fizzbuzz")
                elif i%3==0:
                    print("fizz")
                elif i%7==0:
                    print("buzz")
                else:
                    print(i) 
        else:
            raise ValueError("Your exception message")
    except Exception:
        print("/// ATTENTION:The number you entered was not in between 0 and 99///")   

try:
    enteredNumber = int(input("Please enter a number in between 0 and 99: "))
    fizzbuzz(enteredNumber)
except Exception:
    print("/// ATTENTION: Something went wrong here. Next time, try to enter a valid Integer ////")
```

Also, you must catch specific exceptions instead of catching the generic exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch an exception you need to make sure it will get raised if the desired scenario occurs.

Since the code block between try and except does not raise an exception by itself, you need to raise one by yourself:

```
try:
    if(0<= n <= 99):
        ... 
    else:
        raise Exception()
except Exception:
    ...
```